# Securely pass variable data to different php file

Tags: php, sql, odbc

I'm trying to make a dashboard after my userlogin, however I want it on a different page. But I'm afraid passing data via url might not be necessary caused it can be changed manually. I want to pass `$username` to my dash.php file. Here's my code:

login.php

```
<?php
session_start();
//Insert Connection String
require_once 'config.php';
if(!$_SESSION['username']){
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    echo'<form action="login.php?logged=yes" method="post">';
    echo'<label> Username</label>';
    echo'<input type="text" name="username"/>';
    echo'<label> Passowrd</label>';
    echo'<input type="password" name="password"/>';
    echo'<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login!"/>';
    echo'</form>';
} else {


    //handle some errors
    //If both fields are empty
    if(!$_POST['username'] && !$_POST['password']) {
        echo"Try to login without entering any info, genius.";
    }
    else {
        //check if the username exists
        if(!empty($_POST['username'])) {
            //check if the password exists
            if(!empty($_POST['password'])) {
                //Put unencrypted username variable
               $username = $_POST['username'];
                //Encrypt the values
                $xusername = md5($_POST['username']);
                $xpassword = md5($_POST['password']);
                //Check if they exist in the database
                $query = odbc_exec($conn, "SELECT * FROM xmember WHERE    username='$xusername' AND password='$xpassword'");
                $user_rows = 0;
                while ($row = odbc_fetch_array($query)) {
                    $user_rows++;
                }
                odbc_free_result($query);
                if($user_rows == 1) {
                    echo 'Welcome, '.$_POST['username'];
                    $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
                    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='3;url=dash.php'>";

                }
                else {echo"Sorry, your account information is invalid.";}
            }
            else {echo"Please put your password";}
        }
        else {echo"Please put your username";}

    }   


}
else {echo"what are you doing here?";}
?>
```

config.php

```
<?php
/*
Le Change Nickname PHP v1.0 made by Thor KK Klein LOL
CONFIG section
*/
//Set Network Config
$odbc_dsn = "mydb";
$odbc_user = "sa";
$odbc_password = "wh@tTh3!?";

$conn = odbc_connect($odbc_dsn, $odbc_user, $odbc_password);
if(!$conn) {die('Failed to connect to the database!');}


?>
```

dash.php

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'login.php';//load connection settings and get info

if(!$_SESSION['username']){
    echo"Are you kidding me?";
}else {
    //Display The Dashboard

    //Get user's typical information

    //Get user's table row array
    echo"Welcome, ".$username;
}
?>
```

I tried require-once'ing login.php to my dash.php to get the data.. but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I don't quite get it. You store the usrrname in the session variable, so you sjould be able to acdess it from any file without the need to pass it explicitely or include ahy furyher file.

Comment: i see.. how may i call out the session variable to my dash.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sinde you store the username in the session variable, you can access it from any file usibg `$_SESSION["username"]`. If the key is not set, you can redirect the user to your login page.
Your 'dash.php' file could be modified like this:

```
<?php
require_once("config.php");
session_start();

if(!isSet($_SESSION["username"])) {
    // Redirect user to login page
    header("Location: login.php");
    exit();
}else {
    //Display The Dashboard
    //Get user's typical information
    //Get user's table row array

    echo("Welcome, " . $_SESSION["username"]);
}
?>
```

Comment: thanks! i'm new to php so im still confused at some points. This is my first time creating session login pages.

Comment: is it also possible to assign the session into a variable?

Comment: I don't understand the question. There is probably no need to assign anything to avatiable. The `$_SESSION` variable can beused to store all relevant information about a session. Read more about it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php).